# Words for "size"

Tags: traducción, sinónimos, selección-de-palabras

I know there are multiple words for *size* in Spanish, but I'm quite fuzzy on when to use them.

The two most common seem to be *tamaño* and *talla*, although in some contexts (like shoes), *número* seems correct, too.

Are there any rules for when I ought to use *tamaño* versus *talla*, or are they interchangeable?  And when is *número* the proper translation?  Are there other words I ought to (or can) use in other contexts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say:

- Tamaño: general case, for the dimensions of any object, person, etc.
- Talla: for clothes, shoes, etc.
- Número: for shoes' size

So you can use *talla* for clothes or shoes, but it's not common to use *número* for clothes, although clothes' size is often a number.

By the way, *talla* also means the height of a person.